# On what pages is the facebook app-id useable?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I have registered an facebook app ID with the url http://resihop.nu/facebook/

When I tried the sample code provided on my local computer it didn't render the fbml-elements.

On what pages am I allowed to use the app-id provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because "document.location.protocol" was used for retrieving an javascrtiptfile!